# Using nodal I found vo= -12 V but cannot find the same answer using mesh analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

Using nodal I found vo = -12 V but I can't find the same answer using mesh analysis... I use both clockwise loop for the i meshes and downward i for 8R.

[image]

Came up with this equation: 11Ia - 8Ib = 12 and -2Ia + 14Ib = 0... but I can't get the same answer.

Comment: Solve `V/3+V/6+V/8=12/3+2*(12-V)/6` to find nodal result V=192/23 and therefore Vo=84/23. So I don't find your nodal result.

Comment: kclfor node at center (V/8) + ((V - 2 ((3 (V - 12))/3))/6) + ((V - 12)/3) = 0, and You will find node V=0. then i can just find the current in at Vo, i= (0-12)/3= -4A, then I multiplied it with 3R to get Vo= -12V. The problem is I don't know which method is wrong between my nodal and mesh analysis that's why i'm very confused, i can't sleep well without finding what i did wrong

Comment: while i was doing nodal, I assumed that all currents goes outward is that wrong? book said that you can assume any direction of current and if it's wrong it will just be a negative value.. so if assume a new direction of currents it will be i1-i2-i3=0, which i will get V= 84/23 instead of 0.. i'm confused 84/23 V seems right, which means my mesh analysis is actually right???

Comment: I get it now, because i ignored the direction of current in Vo.. now i need to also reverse the polarity of the dependent source (?) or atleast 2(-Vo) is that right? hays good night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply ... Maple sheet ...

[image]

Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/micro-cap-12-full-cd-version-12.2.0.5) ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to me at top:

> I get it now, because i ignored the direction of current in Vo.. now i
> need to also reverse the polarity of the dependent source (?) or
> atleast 2(-Vo) is that right? hays good night

I'm not sure you do get it, yet.

Look, for nodal purposes (not mesh) your circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fELnUJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's not complicated. You know that \$V_o=12-V\$. And therefore \$V_x=2\cdot\left(12-V\right)\$. So the KCL is:

$$\frac{V-12 \:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{V-0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{V-V_x}{R_3}=0\:\text{A}$$

Substituting in \$V_x\$:

$$\frac{V-12 \:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{V-0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{V-2\cdot\left(12-V\right)}{R_3}=0\:\text{A}$$

Then just solve for \$V\$. Once you have \$V\$ then you have \$V_o\$. It just falls out. And you have all the currents, etc. It's over and done.

Comment: technically my answer vo= -12V is right if only if the current at Vo is reversed but I ignored the given current direction that is connected to a dependent source (imdum)